# How to compute the rank of a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science, computational-complexity, algorithms

Okay, that's a misleading title. This is a somewhat subtler problem than undergraduate linear algebra, although I suspect there's still an easy answer. But I couldn't resist :D.

Here's the actual problem: We're given a *black-box* linear transformation from $V \rightarrow W$, where $V, W$ are vector spaces of dimensions m, n respectively (say m < n), and we want to know if it has full rank. (Numerical considerations aren't an issue; if you want, say it's over a finite field.) This is easy to do in time $O(m^2n)$ and with m calls to the black-box function, just by computing the image of a basis in m and using Gaussian elimination. It's also immediately obvious that we can't do better than m calls to the function in a deterministic algorithm, and I'm pretty sure but haven't quite managed to prove that you can't beat Gaussian elimination asymptotically either.

But can we do better if we just want a probabilistic algorithm? If we're allowed to make as many function calls as we want? What's the best lower bound we can get, probabilistically? These are probably pretty trivial questions (since everything's linear-algebraic and nice), but I just don't know how to approach them.

Comment: By the way, if people really want me to change the title, I will -- particularly if you suggest one! I couldn't think of a good title that conveyed what I wanted it to, and then I thought of the one it currently has, and I couldn't pass up the opportunity. 

Comment: “How to compute the rank of a linear transformation” would be more accurate I think, but I like your little joke. Don't change the title unless confronted by hordes of mathematicians with pitch forks and torches.

Comment: If the algorithm is to be probabilistic, I think it does matter what the field is. For instance, whatever "reasonable" measure you choose to select a random transformation R^m->R^n, the probability that it'll have full rank will be very close to 1, so an algorithm that says "full rank!" without asking any questions is actually a pretty good algorithm. Over a finite field, the situation is obviously different, but if the field is large relative to m, n I suspect you're in the same ball game. Am I misinterpreting your question?

Comment: @Alon: Yeah, I think so. It's easy on average, which is what you're talking about. But I want a randomized algorithm that for *every* black-box function returns the right answer with high probability.

Comment: Gaussian elimination takes longer than O(mn) time, unless you have a revolutionary algorithm, or some a priori knowledge of sparseness.

Comment: @Scott: Good point; I somehow lost a factor of m.

Comment: haha I think its fine to have a misleading title as long as its all fun and games.

Comment: Speak not of abstract vector spaces V and W, but rather V=k^m and W=k^n; i.e., vectors are presented as tuples of elements of k.  If addition and scalar multiplication in V and W are available only as black-box operations, then you get a problem very different from the one I think you mean.  Even worse: if vector space operations are not computable at all, then you get yet another problem - still solvable over a finite field, though, by counting the number of elements in the image, assuming that you are given the cardinality of the ground field and an enumeration of the elements of V!


Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there would be a problem if the transformation was almost independent. If one vector were a combination of the others but otherwise there was independence. I think you would have to compute the image of basis to test for this.

If you want to have a high probability for any every black box function it will have to deal with a distribution with either full rank or rank n-1 and that specific case of rank n-1 with no dependent set of rows smaller than n-2  which looks hard.

I have found a paper on randomized algorithms for computing the rank of a matrix here:

[www.emis.de/journals/ELA/ela-articles/articles/vol11_pp16-23.ps](http://www.emis.de/journals/ELA/ela-articles/articles/vol11_pp16-23.ps)

Comment: Right, that's the argument that shows that you have to make dim(V) function calls, and it's intuitively where the lower bounds should come from, but I don't see how to make it precise.

Comment: Ooh, that paper is nice! Apparently it's an open problem (as of 2004?) over a field of positive characteristic, and they explain where the difficulty is with their methods. Other papers on the authors' webpages are also helpful. I'm tempted to accept this, but I kind of want to see if anyone knows the current status.

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a lower bound on the number of function calls? You say that "we can't do better than m calls to the function in a deterministic algorithm". I would expect the same to be true for a bounded-error probabilistic algorithm as well.

EDIT: I thought I could prove this easily, but now I'm not so sure. Is this what you're asking though?

Comment: A lower bound on the number of function calls would be nice, although I suppose what I really want is the number of basic operations in the base field... And yes, it's definitely trickier than it seems at first glance!

Comment: Interesting. How do you show that you need &Omega;(m) function calls in the deterministic algorithm case? And how in the world do you show that Gaussian elimination is optimal?